# find out how many short and long signals were

Tags: pine-script

how can I display the number of long and short trades in a table for a certain period?
i tried it with the function

```
tostring(barssince(long and window()))
```

where is the window() - time interval where the strategy starts
I need to write a code that will show how many long deals were and how many short deals
for example like this

```
longSignals = 147
ShortSignals = 153
TotalSignals = 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it into variable

```
//@version=4

strategy("My Strategy", overlay=false)

long = bar_index< 100 and (bar_index %2==0)
longclose = bar_index< 100 and (bar_index %2!=0)


window = bar_index > 50

var long_entries = 0
var short_entries = 0


if long
    strategy.entry("EN", strategy.long)
    if (window)
        long_entries += 1

if longclose
    strategy.entry("EN", strategy.short)
    if (window)
        short_entries += 1


var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Long " + tostring(long_entries))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Short " + tostring(short_entries), bgcolor=color.teal)
```